# Не получается логическое условие

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте. У меня не получается реализовать логическое условие для двух переменных .
Способ  обработки - вывод  на  дисплей названия товара,  стоимость  которого превышает 2000 рублей, если таких товаров нет, выдать на дисплей соответствующее сообщение.

```
if (tr1.getTsena() > 2000 && tr2.getTsena()>2000)
    cout << tr1.getName() << tr2.getName() << endl;
else if (tr1.getTsena() > 2000)
    cout << tr1.getName() << endl;
else if (tr2.getTsena() > 2000)
    cout << tr2.getName() << endl;
else 
    cout << "нет товара < 2000"<<endl;
```

Comment: Что не получается? Все должно работать.

Comment: @tilin 
 
если 1 переменная 4567, а вторая 123 то выводи два значения, но мне нужно 1 переменная

Comment: @Гриша Ваш комментарий не соответствует коду в вопросе

Comment: При 4567 и 123 все работает и выводит **Tovar_1**: [вот код](https://ideone.com/hhUNuY)